# 40A mcb. 40A per pole or 40A altogether?

Tags: electrical-engineering

If I have a 40A 3 pole Miniature Circuit Breaker ("mcb"), does this mean 40a per pole or 40A altogether?
The quality standards made me write some more so I do it.

Comment: If we take 40A/3 = 13.33A, which would seem rather a convoluted method to size a wiring system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

40 A per pole.

That's the way three-phase loads are specified so that's the way the breakers are specified.

It also means that a single phase exceeding the trip current (due, for example, to a partial earth fault on that phase) will trip the whole circuit.